# How to get rid of lines on terrain in Unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I making a car game with unity3d. When I played the game on pc, no problem. But when I played it on my android device, screen looks like this photo.

[image]

How to remove these lines on terrain?

Answer (score 0):

Change Texture Compression and Graphics Level.